# JTable how to save the new Row index

Tags: java, jtable, rows

I have the following Problem.
Let's Say I have a JTable with the folowing Values:

1
2
3
4
5

Now I select "3" and press a button which saves the index of the row and prints "3"
I have another Button let's call it the "next button", when I press it it will print "4"

Now I sort (Or in this Case just randomise) the whole Table and it's now like this:

2
5
4
1
3

When I now press the "next button" I want it to print "1" because it's the value after "4".

How can I manage this to work ? 
It already works when I'm not sorting the Table than I can just print the saved row +1...

Is there something like a sort Listener so I can overwrite the saved row with the new value?

Cheers Timothy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you dive into the world of `TableModel`. When programming in Swing it is usually best to split the model from the component straight away. Add a column to the table to handle order, but don't show it.

A simpler method, but a bit of a dead end, is to make the the object stored in the table of a type of your own devising. Just override `toString` to return the display representation.

Comment: yeah of course I use a TableModel. This could actually work that I would have another colum with the ID's. I'll try it out . Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

As i understand that the problem is with the last index , in ur problem that when it's 4 the next one should be 1 . this problem can be done by makeing if condition . 
fore example if i suppose u save the index in a varible rowIndex = 4; 
if(rowIndex ==jTable.getRowCount()-1)
nextRowinsex = 1 ; // which is the first index